# Quisiera saber como comparar un objeto con un bolean porque me sale error de operador !=

Tags: java, map, hashmap

Necesito saber el siguiente error porque no me deja comparar `getcodigoservicio` con `true`

```
public boolean agregarServicio(Serviciosoldado s){
    if(listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio())!=true){ ///el error es en esta linea
        listaservicio.put(s.getCodigoservicio(),s);
        return true;                               
    }else{
        return false;                         
    }                            
}
```

Comment: y si probas con == false en vez de != true?
get() devuelve un boolean?

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/168027)

Answer (score 0):

Doy por hecho que lo que devuelve `listaservicio.get` es un objeto y que dicho objeto no es comparable. Basándome en estas dos suposiciones, un condicional no puede funcionar. En todo caso **el retorno de tu `listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio())` debe ser un booleano (true o false)**.

Saludos

PD: Además, por el nombre de los métodos getCodigoservicio() no parece devolver un booleano y listaservicio parece devolver un objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu método `listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio())` devuelve un `Boolean` y quieres compararlo con otro, puedes utilizar el método `compare()` de la clase `Boolean` de la siguiente forma:

```
public boolean agregarServicio(Serviciosoldado s){
    if(Boolean.compare(listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio(),true) == 0)){
        listaservicio.put(s.getCodigoservicio(),s);
        return true;                               
    }else{
        return false;                         
    }                            
}
```

Te dejo un link donde encontraras mas informacion con ejemplos: [Boolean.compare()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boolean-compare-method-in-java-with-examples/)